# xaml: How to bind CollectionViewSource to a collection of local-instance of class?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, collectionview

I have a class named ***Tasks.cs***:

```
namespace Player_beta.ViewModels
{
    public class Tasks : ICollectionView
    {
        private ICollectionView _customerView;

        public ICollectionView Customers
        {
            get { return _customerView; }
        } 
    public ObservableCollection<PlaylistVM> PlayLists
    {
        get { return _playLists; }
        set { _playLists = value; }
    }
//etc
```

In my ***Window1.xaml*** I wrote:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Player_beta.ViewModels;assembly="
```

Then I've tried to create a local instance of ***Tasks.cs*** and get access to its **PlayLists** property, but failed:

```
    <Window.Resources>
            <local:Tasks x:Key="mtask"/>
            <CollectionViewSource Source="{StaticResource mtask.PlayLists}" x:Key="customerView">
                <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                    <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="plNAME"/>
                </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            </CollectionViewSource>
        </Window.Resources>
........................
 <ListBox DisplayMemberPath="plNAME" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource customerView}}" />
```

I know that I can create an instance of ***Tasks.cs*** in ***Window1.xaml.cs***
and then bind it to Window1's DataContext, but its DataContext already bound to an instance of another class - ***PlayerVM.cs***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you want to achieve by implementing ICollectionView on Task class.

But for you question you need to specify **`Path`** in your binding to bind to property PlayLists :

```
Source="{Binding Path=PlayLists, Source={StaticResource mtask}}"
```

Comment: I am using ICollectionView to sort list of playlists (ObservableCollection<PlaylistVM> PlayLists).